# Why does Users Theme Extension not show up under Gnome Tweak Tool?

Tags: gnome, themes, extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I have want to use user themes for gnome shell, but I am having troubles. I installed the user theme extension, but it doesn't appear to show up under the gnome tweak tool.
To confirm that I have the user themes extension installed, here is the feedback I get when I try to install it through terminal again:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I go under Shell Extensions and there is not option to enable User Themes.

Comment: I can't get this package to show up in a `dpkg -s` or `apt-cache search` lookup. Are you using a PPA?

Comment: Yes, I am using a PPA.

Comment: Did you restart GNOME Shell after installing it? This is required for an extension to show up in GNOME Tweak Tool. Also, what PPA did you use?

Comment: Yes, I forgot. I followed a guide on the internet, but I exited the tab. Do you think I can reinstall it somehow?

Comment: I believe this is the ppa that I used: ppa:ferramroberto/gnome3

Comment: I think @AlinAndrei comment is actually an answer!

Answer (score 6):

*Comment converted to an answer*

After installing the user theme extension, you should restart gnome-shell. Only then would the extension show up in the GNOME tweak tool.

To do that, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter <kbd>r</kbd> in the dialog box. Now gnome-shell would restart and the extension will show up in the tweak tool.

Comment: I have a self created extension which was not showing up in gnome-tweak-tool. After changing the extension name in metadata.json and entering ALT+F2 and restarting gnome-shell with command "r" the extension showed up.